# View a file with specific version in Perforce

Tags: version-control, versioning, perforce

I am new to Perforce and asking for help with following simple questions:

1. How to **list** all the **versions** of a file in Perforce (command-line)
2. How to **view** a **file** with a specific version only.

I searched question 2 online, but didn't have any luck.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe `p4 filelog`, `p4 changes` and `p4 print` will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. "p4 changes" is extremely valuable for me as I often need to search for new changes going into a source-file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. p4 filelog FILENAME
2. p4 print FILENAME#VERSION

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I need. I also wonder if there's another way to view a file (with particular version number) via regular text-editor (say vim). For instance, vim //.../file.txt#3 (to open version 3 of file.txt)

Comment: I use p4v to browse older files in this way. Configure P4V to use vim as your external editor, then browse through the file history to find the version you want, right-click on it and P4V will open it in vim.

Comment: @user1972031, do a `p4 print -o outputfile FILENAME#VERSION`, and that will create an outputfile with which you can use whatever file viewer.

Comment: or even better - `p4 print PATH#VERSION | less` to simply view it with searching capabilities....

Answer (score 0):

And if you don't want to write to a temp file (like others have suggested), you can stream the output to your editor.

For vim/gvim it is:
p4 print FILENAME#VERSION | gvim -

The "-" in the end does the trick.